# Character stuck on box collider 2.5D

Tags: unity, platformer, character, 2.5d

I'm having trouble with my character on a 2.5D platformer. The character get stuck if it collides without reaching the platform's top. Here is a gif showing it: [http://i.imgur.com/jmZ6O1K.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/jmZ6O1K.gifv)

Both colliders (platform and character) has a physics material with no friction (or minimum). So I don't know why is this happening.

Character Collider

[image]

Physic Material

[image]

Comment: can you show the colliders setup on character?

Comment: Sure, done. I've upload the collider setup and the physic material setup

Comment: Also happening with box collider? instead of capsule?

Comment: Yes, also happening...

Comment: So it is due to the force that you are applying on going right, is it so?

Comment: By the your dynamic friction is set to 0.6, give it a try with 0

Comment: Yes, If I release the horizontal key (right arrow) it stops moving and fall off.

If it set the dynamic friction at 0, the character slides on the floor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36061/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-user1423168).

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way the physics engine works. You don't want to use physics for your character's control. Use the [CharacterController](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) instead.

An alternative (but messy) solution is to add a secondary/tertiary collider on the side of each platform and to make it frictionless. This can have unwanted side effects, extra work, and make you feel dirty.

My personal solution is to use Prime31's character controller for 2D, but if you are in 2.5D, I don't think this will work for you.

The reason this is happening is...well, I could make some assumptions, but that's all they would be. So I'll refrain. But imagine if you took a rubber ball and moved it up and towards a wall. It wouldn't just slide up. Anyways, the above solutions should work.